# OpenGL: How much memory anisotropic filtered textures will use?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I'm curious, does the anisotropic texture filtering increase the memory usage? And how to calculate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK it doesn't, but it requires mipmaps, which increase the texture memory usage by 33%.

Comment: I meant compared to normal mip mapped textures. Why is there limits on the max_anisotropy if it doesnt need more memory etc.

Comment: Because it requires more processing power, which affects performance.